# Appending Character to Character Array In C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to Append a character to a character array which represents a String.
I am using a Struct to represent the String.

```
struct String
{   
    char *c;  
    int length;   
    int maxLength;  

}String;
```

**realloc** is messing up my array; when I print my string, it prints random things from memory.
I feel that I am losing the reference to my string by doing realloc.

```
    void appendChar(String *target, char c)
    {
        printf("\String: %s\n", target->c); // Prints the String correctly.     

        int newSize = target->length + 1;
        target->length = newSize;

        if(newSize > target->maxLength)
        {
           // Destroys my String.
            target->c= (char*) realloc (target, newSize * sizeof(char));
            target->maxLength = newSize;
        }


        target->c[newSize-1] = ch;
        target->c[newSize] = '\0';

        printf("String: %s\n", target->c); 
    }
```

Comment: Try `realloc(target->c, newSize * sizeof(char));`. Besides, you can't write to `target->c[newSize]`, the last array cell of the string is `target->c[newSize-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're apllying realloc on your whole structure `target`, you should do :

```
target->c= (char*) realloc (target->c, newSize * sizeof(char));
```